# How do i get the Id of text view with radio Buttons clicked

Tags: ios, swift

For the radioButtons I have used Class in the button and for the indicator to buttons i have used the labels.
These are My TextView

```
@IBOutlet weak var TextViewEveryNewMessage: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TextViewWeekly: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TextViewDaily: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TextViewMonthly: UILabel!
```

These are my Radio Buttons

```
@IBOutlet weak var RadioBtnMonthly: SSRadioButton!
@IBOutlet weak var RadioBtnWeekly: SSRadioButton!
@IBOutlet weak var RadioBtnDefaultChecked: SSRadioButton!
@IBOutlet weak var RadioBtnDaily: SSRadioButton!
```

As soon as i press the ok button i need to save the checkedRadio Button text somewhere and i have done it like this.

```
    @IBAction func OkButton(sender: UIButton) {
    SwiftSpinner.show(kLoadingText)


    if RadioBtnDefaultChecked.selected{
        preferencesConditions.notificationFrequency = self.TextViewEveryNewMessage.text
    }else if RadioBtnDaily.selected{
        preferencesConditions.notificationFrequency = self.TextViewDaily.text
    }else if RadioBtnWeekly.selected{
        preferencesConditions.notificationFrequency =
        self.TextViewWeekly.text
    }else{
        preferencesConditions.notificationFrequency = self.TextViewMonthly.text
    }
```

Is this correct way i am doing.Or there are any other approach. Please suggest me.

Comment: So your UI that you addes textview and Radiobutton .

Comment: I preferred completion block, for this type of scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning a value for `preferencesConditions.notificationFrequency` in `OkButton(sender: UIButton)`, you should do it in each of the `SSRadioButton` buttons and that's by calling *SSRadioButtonControllerDelegate - **didSelectButton***:

```
func didSelectButton(aButton: UIButton?) {
    print(aButton)

    if aButton === RadioBtnDefaultChecked {
        preferencesConditions.notificationFrequency = self.TextViewEveryNewMessage.text
    }else if aButton === RadioBtnDaily {
        preferencesConditions.notificationFrequency = self.TextViewDaily.text
    }else if aButton === RadioBtnWeekly {
        preferencesConditions.notificationFrequency =
            self.TextViewWeekly.text
    }else{
        preferencesConditions.notificationFrequency = self.TextViewMonthly.text
    }
}
```

Don't forget to conform the delegate to the viewController:

```
var radioButtonController: SSRadioButtonsController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    radioButtonController = SSRadioButtonsController(buttons: RadioBtnDefaultChecked, RadioBtnDaily, RadioBtnWeekly)
    radioButtonController!.delegate = self
    radioButtonController!.shouldLetDeSelect = true
}
```

The IBAction should be like:

```
@IBAction func OkButton(sender: UIButton) {
    SwiftSpinner.show(kLoadingText)
}
```

For more information, check [SSRadioButtonsController](https://github.com/shamasshahid/SSRadioButtonsController).

Hope this helped.

Comment: Is mine incorrect.My emulator right now in not working?I will check this later. Thanks for your help.

Comment: IBOutlet weak var TextViewWeekly: UILabel! this label have Weekley as text view and its respective button is  IBOutlet weak var RadioBtnWeekly: SSRadioButton! then as per your suggestion i have implemented the SSRadioButton. But whenever i click to any of the buttons Print(TextViewWeekly.text) gives null.What am i doing wrong here..

Comment: is the iboutlet mapped in storyboard